# How to keep the shape of tf.dataset after applying map?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm creating a tf.dataset object containing 2 images as inputs and a mask as target. All of them are 3D. After applying a custom map, the shape of the object changes from  `<RepeatDataset shapes: (((), ()), ()), types: ((tf.string, tf.string), tf.string)>` to `<PrefetchDataset shapes: (<unknown>, <unknown>, <unknown>), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int32)>`, and when I fit the data, my model throws an error because it only detects one input instead of 2.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
x, y = get_filenames(train_data_path, img_type='FLAIR')
z = get_filenames(train_data_path, img_type='mask')

path_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
mask_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(z)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((path_dataset, mask_dataset)).shuffle(50).repeat(10)

ds = dataset. \
    map(lambda xx, zz: ((tf.py_function(load, [xx], [tf.float32, tf.float32])),
                        tf.py_function(load_mask, [zz], [tf.int32])),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

ds = ds.map(lambda xx, zz: (tf.py_function(random_crop_flip, [xx, zz],
                                           [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int32])),
            num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds = ds.batch(2)
ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

I can't map separately the images and the masks because they need the same seed for the random cropping and flipping. Is it possible to change the shape after the map so that I can feed it to my 2 input model?

**EDIT :**

My random_crop_flip functions is as follows:

```
def random_crop_flip(images, mask, width=128, height=128, depth=128):
    img_bl, img_fu = images
    img_bl = img_bl.numpy()
    img_fu = img_fu.numpy()
    mask = mask.numpy()
    x_rand = random.randint(0, img_bl.shape[2] - width)
    y_rand = random.randint(0, img_bl.shape[1] - height)
    z_rand = random.randint(0, img_bl.shape[3] - depth)
    img_bl_f = img_bl[:, y_rand:y_rand + height, x_rand:x_rand + width, z_rand:z_rand + depth, :]
    img_fu_f = img_fu[:, y_rand:y_rand + height, x_rand:x_rand + width, z_rand:z_rand + depth, :]
    mask_f = mask[:, y_rand:y_rand + height, x_rand:x_rand + width, z_rand:z_rand + depth, :]
    flip_x = random.choice([True, False])
    flip_y = random.choice([True, False])
    flip_z = random.choice([True, False])

    if flip_x:
        img_bl_f = np.flip(img_bl_f, axis=2)
        img_fu_f = np.flip(img_fu_f, axis=2)
        mask_f = np.flip(mask_f, axis=2)

    if flip_y:
        img_bl_f = np.flip(img_bl_f, axis=1)
        img_fu_f = np.flip(img_fu_f, axis=1)
        mask_f = np.flip(mask_f, axis=1)

    if flip_z:
        img_bl_f = np.flip(img_bl_f, axis=3)
        img_fu_f = np.flip(img_fu_f, axis=3)
        mask_f = np.flip(mask_f, axis=3)

    images = zip(img_bl_f, img_fu_f)
    return images, mask_f
```

The zip isn't solving my problem. Is it possible to modify the return to get my desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The images are 3D and of Niftii type (neuroimaging), so I can't use native tf functions to load them. And I also believe that random flip is not implemented for 3D images. Any ideas on how so set the shape after a map?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, because RGB images are in 3D.

Comment: 4D I mean, 3D grayscale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem by "flattening" (eliminating the parenthesis) the return of the random_crop_flip, and applying another map on top of them, where I specified the shapes and returned my desired structure (x ,y), z:

```
def _set_shapes(img_bl, img_fu, mask):
    img_bl.set_shape([128, 128, 128, 1])
    img_fu.set_shape([128, 128, 128, 1])
    mask.set_shape([128, 128, 128, 1])

    return (img_bl, img_fu), mask
```

Then my code looks like this:

```
x, y = get_filenames(train_data_path, img_type='FLAIR')
z = get_filenames(train_data_path, img_type='mask')

path_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
mask_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(z)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((path_dataset, mask_dataset)).shuffle(50).repeat(10)

ds = dataset. \
    map(lambda xx, zz: ((tf.py_function(load, [xx], [tf.float32, tf.float32])),
                        tf.py_function(load_mask, [zz], [tf.int32])),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

ds = ds.map(lambda xx, zz: (tf.py_function(random_crop_flip, [xx, zz],
                                           [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int32])),
            num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds = ds.map(_set_shapes)
ds = ds.batch(2)
ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```